# Why I can't use math operations with jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I can not use mathematical operations with jsPDF library. I need to get some values from html inputs and I need to use these values my jsPDF function. Because I want to calculate something and I want to write that to a pdf document. I tried to parse my input values but I can't use parseInt, parseFloat and Number methods with jsPDF. How can I do that?

This part doesn't work:

```
musteri = parseInt(document.getElementById("musteri").value);
bolge = parseInt(document.getElementById("bolge").value);
doc.text(100,184,(musteri));
doc.text(100,192,(bolge));
doc.text(100,210,(musteri + bolge));
```

Comment: can you put any code snippet you done?

Comment: musteri = parseInt(document.getElementById("musteri").value);
 bolge = parseInt(document.getElementById("bolge").value);
 doc.text(100,184,(musteri));
 doc.text(100,192,(bolge));
 doc.text(100,210,(musteri + bolge));

This type is not working.

Comment: what does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? And what makes you think you can't use parseInt() or parseFloat()? What did you actually try, and what went wrong? It doesn't make much sense, there should be no restriction on those.

Comment: Firstly, I want to get inputs' values. After than I want to write the field to pdf that on the 5th line. But I must to calculate a variable before that. I don't get an error. Just my function didn't work. Any error, any console log. My english is not good, if I couldn't explain my problem, sorry for that.